# How to prevent disappearing of a box content when clicking outside or pressing escape in jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Iam working with ecommerce site.There I have to create a popup for age verification.I have created a popup box for verification of age.It work's properly but when I clicking outside the box disappears.The box should not disappear even after clicking outside or pressing escape also.How can I prevent disappearing the box after clicking outside also?
Below is my Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({
        'width': maskWidth,
        'height': maskHeight
    });

    //transition effect  
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.9);

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
    $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window #close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

});
```

```css
#mask {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9000;
    background-color: #000;
    display: none;
}

#boxes .window {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 20px;
    /*    border-radius: 15px;*/
    text-align: center;
}

#boxes #dialog {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.maintext {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#lorem {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <md-card>
        <div style="display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">
            <h2 style="margin:20px;color:red"><b>SIMPLYSALT</b></h2><br>
            <div id="lorem">
                <h3><b>Are You Sure You're 21</b> </h3>
                <h4>Sorry,dog years don't count</h4>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <button href="http://webenlance.com/" id="close" class="agree btn-lg btn-success" align="center" style="color:white;padding:5px">Yup,I'm 21 years age or Older</button></div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 1478px; font-size: 32pt; color:white; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask"></div>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the functions that do this.

**JS(Remove):**

```
//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: But when I click on yes button,it needs to be disappear

Comment: @srujana Then don't remove the second function!, updated my answer!